# Скрытие области

Tags: javascript

Есть поиск, как в Твиттере или в ВК, когда печатаешь в поле вылазит область с результатами. Мне надо сделать так, что-бы, когда пользователь кликает в другую область, то поиск исчезает вместе с результатами, при это когда кликаешь на саму область результатов, то не чего не исчезает. Как это сделать? Есть такой вариант

```
var resultSearchMouse = 0 // 1- Мышь находится на области 0 - курсор ушел

resultSearch.onmouseout = handleMouseLeave(function(e) {
    resultSearchMouse = 0 
});

resultSearch.onmouseover = handleMouseEnter(function(e) {
   resultSearchMouse = 1
});

document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(resultSearchMouse == 0){
        resultSearch.style.display = 'none'
    } 
});
```

Comment: направление правильное, чем не устраивает ?

Comment: мне просто интересно, как другие это осуществляют?

Comment: примерно так-же, только можно прям в хэндлере на документе получить объект по которому кликнули, чтобы переменную не держать

Comment: Лучше будет resultSearchMouse = true